# how to show database in phpmyadmin in web browser

Tags: phpmyadmin

Excuse me, guys.
Can you help me, how to show database in phpmyadmin in web browser (in tabular form) in Ubuntu 13.10 ?
I've installed phpmyadmin mysql-server apache2 and php5...

Answer (score 0):

Is phpmyadmin working? If not, do this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

Make sure apache and mysql are running:

```
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service mysql start
```

And then, point your web browser to:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Of course, phpmyadmin running well in my machine.
But, I can't show all database query in tabular form in my web browser

Comment: OK, sorry I misunderstood the question, I thought it wasn't working at all.